# Sort array of month year jquery

Tags: javascript, sorting, momentjs

```
var monthYear = ["Jan-2016", "Jul-2015", "Jul-2016", "Mar-2016", "Aug-2016", "Mar-2015"];
```

I wanted it to be sorted :

```
[ "Mar-2015", "Jul-2015", "Jan-2016", "Mar-2016", "Jul-2016", "Aug-2016" ]
```

Code that I m following

```
var sorted = monthYear.sort(function(a,b) {
    a = a.split("-");
    b = b.split("-")
    return new Date(a[1], a[0], 1) - new Date(b[1], b[0], 1)
});
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder    ascending by comparing month and year

Comment: What in your research has lead you to believe the `Date` constructor understands `"Jan"`, `"Feb"`, etc.?

Comment: I even tried with moment.js @T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 4):

If moment.js is an option, just parse your string with it:

```
var sorted = monthYear.sort(function(a,b) {
    return +moment(a,'MMM-YYYY') - moment(b,'MMM-YYYY');
});
```

Comment: Explanation: `+moment` or `moment.unix()` will convert the parsed moment objects to timestamps, and by subtracting, you'd get the sort function.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor don't undestand the short versions of the months.

You can create a JSON object with the short versions and their respective name and sort by the value of the key.

```
var monthYear = ["Jan-2016", "Jul-2015", "Jul-2016", "Mar-2016", "Aug-2016", "Mar-2015"];

var months = {
  Jan: "January",
  Feb: "February",
  Mar: "March",
  Apr: "April",
  May: "May",
  Jun: "June",
  Jul: "July",
  Aug: "August",
  Sep: "September",
  Oct: "October",
  Nov: "November",
  Dec: "December"
}

var sorted = monthYear.sort(function(a,b) {
    a = a.split("-");
    b = b.split("-")
    return new Date(months[a[0]] + a[1]) - new Date(months[b[0]] + b[1])
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think your logic is quite correct, the only problem is that the strings `Jan`, `Feb` ... can't be used in the `Date()` constructor, as it accepts a `number` for the month value.

What you can do is to use an object that contains all respective numbers for these months values, and use it in your sort function:

```
var months = {Jan : 1, Feb: 2, Mar: 3, Apr: 4, May: 5, Jun: 6, Jul: 7, Aug: 8, Sep: 9, Oct: 10, Nov: 11, Dec: 12};
```

And in your sort function write:

```
var sorted = monthYear.sort(function(a, b) {
  a = a.split("-");
  b = b.split("-")
  return new Date(a[1], monthsObject[a[0]] - 1, 1) - new Date(b[1], monthsObject[b[0]] - 1, 1)
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var monthYear = ["Jan-2016", "Jul-2015", "Jul-2016", "Mar-2016", "Aug-2016", "Mar-2015"];

var months = {
  Jan: 1,
  Feb: 2,
  Mar: 3,
  Apr: 4,
  May: 5,
  Jun: 6,
  Jul: 7,
  Aug: 8,
  Sep: 9,
  Oct: 10,
  Nov: 11,
  Dec: 12
};

var sorted = monthYear.sort(function(a, b) {
  a = a.split("-");
  b = b.split("-")
  return new Date(a[1], monthsObject[a[0]] - 1, 1) - new Date(b[1], monthsObject[b[0]] - 1, 1)
});
console.log(sorted);
```